# videoplayer plugin not working for cordova/phonegap

Tags: android, git, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I tried below plugins in cmd prompt which are not working:
`cordova plugin add com.moust.cordova.videoplayer
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.videoplayer
cordova plugin add https://github.com/moust/cordova-plugin-videoplayer.git`

Showing error:
Registry returned 404 for GET on https://registry.npmjs.org/org.cordova.videoplayer

Thanks for help in Advance!

Answer (score -2):

Seem have to be installed using

`cordova plugin add https://github.com/moust/cordova-plugin-videoplayer.git`